# fmincon - too many constraints - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

Suppose I have a fmincon function. As we know from matlab documentation we can impose linear and nonlinear constraints.

Suppose now I have a function of 3 parameters to optimize.
And I want 3 of them to be greater than 0 and 1 of them to be greater than -1 I would need 4 constraints but I get an error.

Simple example (working code):

```
A=eye(4)
A(4,4)=-1;
b=100*ones(4,1)
b(4,1)=+1
fun = @(x)100*(x(2)-x(1)^2)^2 + (1-x(1))^2+x(3);
fmincon(fun,[0,0,0],A,b)
```

The error is

*Error using fmincon (line 287)
A must have 3 column(s).*

It is strange that A can only have n constraints (that you could add with non linear)

Thanks

Comment: Please give us the exact error message that you get and also the `size` of the parameters that you pass to `fmincon`.

Comment: I have added a simple example

Comment: YOur init guess has three elts, but the matrix A is expecting to operate on a 4 elt. You may have meant to create a 4x3 matrix (which will be 4 inequality constraints)

Comment: Alexandre, you are so right! I was very stupid. Thanks a lot. I guess you could create an answer so other people do not make the same mistake. Even if I do not understand why shouldn't I give n starting values with n number of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `fun` expects exactly three inputs, i.e. the vector `x` will always be 3x1. So your starting point *must* be a 3x1 vector, *not* 4x1. The `fmincon` function allows you to specify *any* number of linear constraints of the form `Ax ≤ b`. Here, the `Ax` is a [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication): each column in `A` corresponds to one of the dimensions of `x`, thus `A` has to have exactly three columns. The number of rows can be any arbitrary number - though of course `b` will have to have the same dimension!

Small example: if you have the inequality `3*x + 4*y - z ≤ 1`, then the first row of `A` is `[3, 4, -1]`. And the first entry of `b` is `1`. Now, let's make up an additional constraint, e.g. `y ≤ 4`, so you have to add a row `[0, 1, 0]` to `A` and `4` to `b`. Your matrices are

```
A = [3, 4, -1;
     0, 1, 0];
b = [1; 4];
```

In your case, you want more conditions than variables. You can do that by calling [`eye`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) with two parameters: number of rows and number of columns:

```
>> A = eye(4, 3);
A =
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     0
```

and manually add the last constraint:

```
A(4,:) = [0, 0, -1];
```

To implement the constraint, that all parameters have to be greater than 0, and `z` has to be smaller than 1, you can create your matrices as follows:

```
A = -eye(4, 3);
A(4,:) = [0, 0, 1];
b = [zeros(3,1); 1];
```

i.e. the equations are:

`-1 * x ≤ 0`, which equals `x ≥ 0` 
`-1 * y ≤ 0`, which equals `y ≥ 0` 
`-1 * z ≤ 0`, which equals `z ≥ 0` 
`z ≤ 1`

now, you can use `fmincon`:

```
>>fmincon(fun, zeros(3,1), A, b);
ans =
    1.0000
    1.0000
    0.0000
```

Comment: Why do I have to give necessarly 4 starting point? otherwise it does not wok

Comment: No, *very* important: do *not* give 4 starting points!  As your function expects 3 parameters, give 3 starting points - as in the last example in my answer. The error was in your matrix `A`: it had 4 columns instead of 3 columns. As explained in my answer, the number of columns always has to be the same as the number of parameters, i.e. 3.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of treating the the two absolute constraints as 4 separate linear constrains why not treat them as a 2 nonlinear constrains specifically. x^2 < 9 ?

Comment: Good idea. Can you add an example to your question, where you show how to do that?

Comment: I was thinking about that but it was odd in my opinion that it was not possible to solve it with linear constraints! And I was courious about it